# Isolated MOSFET gate driver VCC and VDD power suppl

Tags: power-electronics, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, powermosfet

I am planning to use UCC21520 for HV SiC MOSFET based full bridge  design. My operation frequency would be around 100kHz.  I selected UCC21520 in order to achieve the isolation between the power and signal side. However, during design I am stuck at deciding how to select power supply for the VCC and VDDA/B.

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sluscq2b/sluscq2b.pdf

[image]

My questions are following:

1. If I use same power supply for VCC and VDDA/VDDB ( say 15V) would that work? I would use a laboratory 15V power supply ( isolated) and connect the ground of the power supply to the ground pin of the IC.
2. If I indeed need to use two power supplies say 3,3V +GND1  for VCC and 15V +GND2 for both VDDs, how do I deal with two new ground points? and how would they connected to the GND pin of the IC.
3. Speaking of grounds, I am planning to carry over the PWM signal to H-Bridge board from another PCB that has its own auxiliary power supply. I will carry over the PWM signals and and respective ground ( SGND) to the H_bridge PCB. How should I deal with this SGND with respect to aforementioned GND1 (and /or GND2).

Since, aim of using the IC is to achieve isolation from SGND and PGND, I am really confused how to deal with other grounds ? Your kind support is solicited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, it won't work. the supply of the high-side transistor (VDDA) needs to be floating. That is normally achieved by using a bootstrap circuit or a dc/dc convertor.
2. You need two supplies for the secondary (VDDs). The low-side can be a "normal" 15V but the high-side needs to be floating.
3. It is normally recommended to joing signal gorund and power ground on one point only (called sometimes star connection)

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in almost anything. If you use an isolated gate driver, then it's obviously that GND and VSSA and VSSB should have no connection, else you don't need an isolated driver. 
For the fully controlled solution 0 to 100% PWM you need three power supplies. The VCC, VDDA and VDDB, last two shall have high insulation voltage. If you plan to drive a half bridge with  being drived less than PWM DT 100%, you could use a bootstrap circuit, but it would be a challenge for such high frequency. What's the problem of [TIDA-01159 Reference Design](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiducg2/tiducg2.pdf) ?